# Langchain agents

Tags: python, agent, langchain, large-language-model

I have a problem using Langchain agent with Serpapi together with a local LLM.  I have successfully do the same thing when I connect with OpenAI.

My local LLM is either the MPT-7B model and the 30B_Lazarus on text generation mode.

My codes looks like this.

```
from langchain.agents import load_tools
from langchain.agents import initialize_agent
import json

query="Get Microsoft share price from the www.bloomberg.com and include the url where you got this information."

llm = HuggingFacePipeline(pipeline=generate_text)
toolkit = load_tools(["serpapi"], llm=llm, serpapi_api_key=SERPAPI_API_KEY)
agent = initialize_agent(toolkit, llm, agent="zero-shot-react-description", verbose=True, return_intermediate_steps=True)
response = agent({"input":query})
```

The verbose message looks like this.

Entering new chain...

I should search for the information on the internet

Action: Search for the information on the internet

Action Input: [www.bloomberg.com](http://www.bloomberg.com)

Observation: Search for the information on the internet is not a valid tool, try another one.

Thought: I should use a search engine to find the information

Action: Search for the information on a search engine

Action Input: Microsoft share price

Observation: Search for the information on a search engine is not a valid tool, try another one.

Answer (score 1):

this `agent="zero-shot-react-description"` is not the right agent type for the search engine. you should be using [self_ask_with_search](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/agents/agent_types/self_ask_with_search) agent type:

```
from langchain import OpenAI, SerpAPIWrapper
from langchain.agents import initialize_agent, Tool
from langchain.agents import AgentType

# you can define a different llm
llm = OpenAI(temperature=0)
search = SerpAPIWrapper()
tools = [
    Tool(
        name="Intermediate Answer",
        func=search.run,
        description="useful for when you need to ask with search",
    )
]

self_ask_with_search = initialize_agent(
    tools, llm, agent=AgentType.SELF_ASK_WITH_SEARCH, verbose=True
)
self_ask_with_search.run(
    "What is the hometown of the reigning men's U.S. Open champion?"
)
```